# Как пересечь историю при соединении таблиц

Tags: sql, база-данных, postgresql

Есть две таблицы:

Table1(id, param1, param2, date_from, date_to):

```
(1, 'z', 55, '01.05.2010 12:30:20', '17.05.2010 13:10:14'),
(1, 'c', null, '17.05.2010 13:10:15', '18.01.2010 04:13:15'),
(1, 'c', 25, '18.01.2010 04:13:16', '01.01.9999 00:00:00');
```

Table2(id, param3, date_from, date_to):

```
(1, 15, '01.04.2010 12:30:20', '02.05.2010 13:10:14'),
(1, 35, '02.05.2010 13:10:15', '01.01.9999 00:00:00');
```

Необходимо чтобы при объединении 2х таблиц были поля содержащие историю изменения каждого параметра. То есть:

Select(id, param1, param2, param3, date_from, date_to):

```
(1, null, null, 10, '01.04.2010 12:30:20', '01.05.2010 12:30:19'),
(1, 'z', 55, 15, '01.05.2010 12:30:20', '02.05.2010 13:10:14'),
(1, 'z', 55, 35, '02.05.2010 13:10:15', '17.05.2010 13:10:14'),
(1, 'c', null, 35, '17.05.2010 13:10:15', '18.01.2010 04:13:15'),
(1, 'c', 25, 35, '18.01.2010 04:13:16', '01.01.9999 00:00:00');
```

Там где записи из двух таблиц не пересекались во времени(или часть времени) должны выводится null.

Пока что я сделал:

```
SELECT a.id, param1, param2, param3, a.dfrom as afrom, a.dto as ato, b.dfrom as bfrom, b.dto as bto
FROM Table1 a LEFT JOIN Table2 b ON a.id = b.id
UNION
SELECT id, null as param1, null as param2, param3, null as afrom, null as bfrom, dfrom, dto
FROM Table2
```

И дальше не понимаю как действовать...

Comment: Если промежуток А и промежуток В пересеклись на 1 секунду, то какой результат строки будет?

Answer (score 0):

1. Получить список всех уникальных дат из 4-х столбцов: Table1.date_from, Table1.date_to, Table2.date_from, Table2.date_to в порядке возрастания. Я бы делал через UNION 4-х подзапросов.
2. Для каждой даты из этого списка получить следующую дату из этого же списка. Тут возможны варианты.

   2.1 Запрос из п.1 запихнуть в CTE, добавить номер по порядку с помощью ROW_NUMBER и соединить с самим собой. При большом количестве записей сильно не оптимально.

   2.2 Хранимая процедура с курсором и двумя переменными
3. Имея на руках две даты, гарантированно не выходящих за пару date_from, date_to каждой из таблицы, получить значения параметров простым SELECT (LEFT JOIN)